# Attempt to invoke interface method on a null object reference and I don't know how to solve it

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-room

I'm new to Android Studio and I'm learning on how to use Fragament Dialog from inside a Fragment. I'd like to ask why it says "null objext reference".

Here is the code for the fragment :

```
public class PelangganFragment extends Fragment implements CreatePelangganDialog.CreatePelangganListener,
        PelangganLVAdapter.OnPelangganClickListner,
        UpdatePelangganDialog.UpdatePelangganListener {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private View parent;
    private Context context;

    private PelangganViewModel mViewModel;
    private FragmentPelangganBinding fragmentPelangganBinding;
    private PelangganLVAdapter mAdapter;

    public static PelangganFragment newInstance() {
        return new PelangganFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pelanggan, container, false);
        mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(PelangganViewModel.class);


        fragmentPelangganBinding = FragmentPelangganBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);
        View root = fragmentPelangganBinding.getRoot();

        parent = root.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        FloatingActionButton fab = root.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        mRecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        //context = this;
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        //Set adapter to RecyclerView
        mAdapter = new PelangganLVAdapter();
        mAdapter.setItemOnClick(this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openCreatePelangganDialog();
            }
        });


        return root;
    }

    private void openCreatePelangganDialog() {
        CreatePelangganDialog createPelangganDialog = new CreatePelangganDialog();
        createPelangganDialog.show(
                getChildFragmentManager(), CreatePelangganDialog.TAG);
    }


    @Override
    public void saveNewPelanggan(ListViewModelPelanggan pelanggan) {
        mViewModel.insert(pelanggan);
        snackBar("Pelanggan Saved");
    }
}
```

here is the code for the FragmentDialog, the error occurs on this class and I commented on which line the error occurs :

```
public class CreatePelangganDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private EditText mNama;
    private EditText mNik;
    private EditText mALamat;
    private EditText mPekerjaan;
    private EditText mKeperluan;
    private Button mSaveBtn;
    private CreatePelangganListener mListener;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pelanggan_dialog,null);

        builder.setView(view);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle("Tambah Pelanggan");

        mNama = view.findViewById(R.id.et_nama);
        mNik = view.findViewById(R.id.et_nik);
        mALamat = view.findViewById(R.id.et_alamat);
        mPekerjaan = view.findViewById(R.id.et_Pekerjaan);
        mKeperluan = view.findViewById(R.id.et_keperluan);
        mSaveBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_save);

        mSaveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String nama = mNama.getText().toString();
                String nik = mNik.getText().toString();
                String alamat = mALamat.getText().toString();
                String pekerjaan = mPekerjaan.getText().toString();
                String keperluan = mKeperluan.getText().toString();

                if(nama.isEmpty()||nik.isEmpty()||alamat.isEmpty()||pekerjaan.isEmpty()||keperluan.isEmpty()) {
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    ListViewModelPelanggan pelanggan = new ListViewModelPelanggan(nama,nik,alamat,
                            pekerjaan,keperluan);
                    mListener.saveNewPelanggan(pelanggan); //the error occurs here
                    dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mListener = (CreatePelangganListener) getTargetFragment();
    }

    public interface CreatePelangganListener{
        void saveNewPelanggan(ListViewModelPelanggan pelanggan);
    }

    public static String TAG = "Tambah Pelanggan Dialog";
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't dump all your code (including commented-out methods) on us. Instead provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, a stack trace would help in narrowing the problem down.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca oops, my bad. It's my first time asking on this site, is it better now though?

Comment: Yes, much better. Now let's wait and see if someone has an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by replacing `getTargetFragment()` with `getParentFragment()` in these lines

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mListener = (CreatePelangganListener) getParentFragment();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand this specific code, however, this error is easily solvable by opening "run" at the bottom of the screen, scrolling up, and you'll see at which line you've tried to invoke the null object reference.
generally, this problem shows up when you activate a function with/on the null object, good luck.

Comment: I did open the "run" part and it showed the error on the line that I have commented. I reread the codes several times but I still don't get on why it says null pointer exception. Thank you, good luck for you too.